# Toggle Twitter Bootstrap button class when active

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In twitter bootstrap, I was looking for a way to allow a button to be the default color when not active.  Once a button is active, I wanted to change the color of it.  I looked at ways of doing it with the js file that was provided.  I ended up writting a little script to handle this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By adding `class-toggle` as an attribute to the button equaling what you would like to go to once the button is pressed and adding the following jQuery, you will get the result described above.

```
$('.btn-group > .btn, .btn[data-toggle="button"]').click(function() {

        if($(this).attr('class-toggle') != undefined && !$(this).hasClass('disabled')){
            var btnGroup = $(this).parent('.btn-group');

            if(btnGroup.attr('data-toggle') == 'buttons-radio') {
                btnGroup.find('.btn').each(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass($(this).attr('class-toggle'));
                });
                $(this).addClass($(this).attr('class-toggle'));
            }

            if(btnGroup.attr('data-toggle') == 'buttons-checkbox' || $(this).attr('data-toggle') == 'button') {
                if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    $(this).removeClass($(this).attr('class-toggle'));
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass($(this).attr('class-toggle'));
                }
             }

          }


      });
```

Then the button would look like

```
<button class="btn" data-toggle="button" class-toggle="btn-inverse">Single Toggle</button>
```

If you want to do it with a button group as well it works the same way.  Just add the `class-toggle` to each button in the group.

[The jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9hUr/94)

**UPDATE**

I have modified and created a gist to have a better response when starting you button with a class.  [Toggle Twitter Bootstrap Classes](https://gist.github.com/bretterer/5103273)

**UPDATE**

I have made a change to fix the bug that appears when you click on an active radio button

[Find it here](http://jsfiddle.net/W9hUr/120/)

Comment: Thanks for the gist ! However, in the radio buttons case, when you click twice on the same button, a glitch appears.

Comment: @BabyAzerty I have updated it to fix this.   see last update or http://jsfiddle.net/W9hUr/120/

Comment: Hi thank you for this post. However, it does not work you assign a second click event to the button (later in the script). Is there a propper way to deal with this case or do i have to call the function each time i want to have the classes switched in a button group / button?

Comment: Im not sure i understand what you are saying @mffap

Comment: @mffap  take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/W9hUr/151/ and click on the yes button.   You will see I have a click handler on that button to add a message.  I think this is what you were saying

Answer (score 14):

I don't think, that any JS is really necessary.
I believe that this can by done **purely by CSS and `data` attributes**.

Yes, it involves a little *CSS duplication*, but still better than sometimes glitchy javascript.

1. Add data attribute `data-active-class` to button,
2. Add custom CSS for all classes (example of one for readability; colors are taken from already existing classes "primary", "success", and so on)

   ```
   .btn.active[data-active-class="primary"] {
       color: #fff;
       background-color: #286090;
       border-color: #204d74;
   }
   ```

*Inactive button* will render as usual, *active* based on `data-*` attribute will render by this^^ CSS.

[JSFiddle with complete CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/ms040m01/3/)

**Edit:**
When using SASS or LESS the colors can/should be used from variables already defined by Bootstrap... that solves the *duplicating* problem.

Comment: @bretterer Please consider whether this answer satisfy your needs :)

Comment: Am I missing something? Could not get this to work in the fiddle provided.

Comment: @Khrys Tried this on several PCs (even on my phone), with no problem, could you please provide more info of what is wrong? There's only some html and css, no javascript, maybe there's something wrong with external resources (missing bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css)?

Comment: Well, weird... I tried in JSFiddle itself and I am sure it wasn't working. But now it is. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Hi @bard, sorry for a delay. What do you mean by single active? Do you mean something different other than "Single Toggle" button that is in the example? It has a default color and active color, both can be different.

Comment: I am voting up! This will prevent bugs when dealing with async behavior...

Answer (score 3):

I've edited your code. If you click on an active state in your code, it all messes up. I've added a little if statement which prevents this. Just a contribution if ya'll need the fix. Good work with the code.

```
$('.btn-group > .btn, .btn[data-toggle="button"]').click(function() {
var buttonClasses = ['btn-primary','btn-danger','btn-warning','btn-success','btn-info','btn-inverse'];
var $this = $(this);

    if ($(this).attr('class-toggle') != undefined && !$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {

        var btnGroup = $this.parent('.btn-group');
        var btnToggleClass = $this.attr('class-toggle');
        var btnCurrentClass = $this.hasAnyClass(buttonClasses);

        if(btnToggleClass!='false'&&btnToggleClass!='btn') {

            if (btnGroup.attr('data-toggle') == 'buttons-radio') {
                var activeButton = btnGroup.find('.btn.active');
                var activeBtnClass = activeButton.hasAnyClass(buttonClasses);

                    activeButton.removeClass(activeBtnClass).addClass(activeButton.attr('class-toggle')).attr('class-toggle',activeBtnClass);               
                    $this.removeClass(btnCurrentClass).addClass(btnToggleClass).attr('class-toggle',btnCurrentClass);

            }

            if (btnGroup.attr('data-toggle') == 'buttons-checkbox' || $this.attr('data-toggle') == 'button') {
                $this.removeClass(btnCurrentClass).addClass(btnToggleClass).attr('class-toggle',btnCurrentClass);
            }

        }


    }



});    

$.fn.hasAnyClass = function(classesToCheck) {
    for (var i = 0; i < classesToCheck.length; i++) {
        if (this.hasClass(classesToCheck[i])) {
            return classesToCheck[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
```

Sincerely Another Bootstrap Lover