# Render radio as button/image simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm using SimpleForm and was able to create a list of radios. Is there a way that I can render them as buttons or images?

I did some search and tried this:

```
- f.collection_radio_buttons(:category, [['Male', 'icon_male'], ['Female', 'icon_female']], :first, :last) do |category|
  = category.label { image_tag("/assets/icons/16x16/#{category.text}.png") + category.radio_button  }
```

However, it still renders the radio icon, see below

[image]

Is there a way to render it as just images that's selectable or as buttons similar to Twitter Bootstrap button? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons

Also, this requires me to specify the list of images in the view, I need it to be driven off the model, something like `category.image_url`

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11267138/1478467) interesting. Needs a bit of JS though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using simple_form's radio element. I simply resorted to jQuery and a hidden input element.